# outlier treatment in r for extreme outliers

Tags: r

I am doing a school project and I have located some outliers in one of my columns. I believe these outliers are hurting my correlation test. I have used the following code to identify them,

```r
boxplot(df$col)
boxplot(df$col)$out
outliers <- boxplot(df$col)$out
```

after my identification, how should I treat them? Could you provide some code that I could plug in that will treat them automatically. I know for a fact that there are two extreme outliers. Would yall recommend just treating those and leaving the rest? If so what would the code be... they are over 2000 and are the only two numbers above 100.

Comment: How to deal with outliers is always contextual (and sometimes personal). Even when I remove them from a plot (in order to keep the axis scale manageable, for instance), I still mark that they were taken out (in writing if not a hollow dot at the plot extreme).

Comment: I want to replace it with the mean because I need to maintain the integrity of the data for regression/correlation analysis. How do I go about doing this? I have them detected and my heart is set on treating them with the mean.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Nullify outliers: out_free_df => data.frame 
out_free_df <- within(df, {
    col <- ifelse(col %in% boxplot.stats(col)$out, NA, x)
    }
  )

# Impute outliers with mean: imputed_df => data.frame
imputed_df <- within(out_free_df, {col <- ifelse(is.na(col), mean(col, na.rm = TRUE), col)}
```

Comment: If you're using `df$col` (a vector), you don't need `sapply`. Just to the vector ops directly. (If you want to keep `sapply` then replace `ifelse` with a traditional `if`/`else` statement.) Also, since you're `within(df, ...)`, you don't need `df$` anywhere inside of it. Also, I suggest you calculate your boxplot stats *once* and reuse it, no need to re-calculate it `nrow(df)` times.